# Pandas: apply tupleize_cols to dataframe without to_csv()?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I like the tupleize_cols option in the to_csv() function. Is this function available on a in-memory dataframe? I would like to clean up the tuples of the multi-indexed columns to 'reportable' column names automatically.

Thanks,

Luc

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.values` on the index

```
In [1]: i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3],['a','b','c']])

In [2]: i
Out[2]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], [u'a', u'b', u'c']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

In [3]: i.values
Out[3]: 
array([(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'),
       (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')], dtype=object)
```